# Multiple views referring each other performance

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-view

I have a view that I consider as a base view , it's a view on a table something like this

```
Create View BaseView
select * from table where date>=x and date<=y
```

now this view acts as a reference for further views

for example

```
Create View ChildView1
Select * from Childtable where baseviewID in(select Id from Baseview)
```

this is a chain that will continue for more tables.

Considering the fact that BaseView is derived from a table with about 50k + records and all the views are going to be requested by WebAPI in the same order

Baseview->ChildView1->ChildView2 and so on

Does the baseview results get fetched every time the childview is called as every view in turn has a parent in BaseView

Asking this from performance point of view. I am confused If it will hamper performance much or does SQL will cache the view for further immediate requests?

Comment: Actually nesting views is a timebomb for horrible performance. It totally confuses the optimizer and you will get some unbelievably poor performance. Check out this article on the topic. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven